# Python - Run numpy without the python interpreter

Tags: python, numpy

I have an .x3d code which references a python script. I am trying to implement certain functions which make use of the numpy module. However, I am only able to import the builtin modules from Python.

I am looking for a way to import the numpy module into the script without having to call the interpreter (i.e. "test.py", instead of "python test.py").

Currently I get "ImportError: No module named numpy".

My question is: Is there a way to import the numpy module without having to call from the interpreter? Is there a way to include numpy as one of the built-in modules of Python?

Comment: Are you running this in a webserver, local machine, remote machine, desktop...? Why is that you cannot use `python test.py`?

Comment: @heltonbiker, I am running it on a local machine, but it is actually an .x3d script which queries from the python script. This is why I cannot run it with "python test.py"

Comment: What is x3d? Do you have python inside an x3d script? How do you run the script?

Comment: print sys.executable both in the .x3d and running python from the command line

Comment: By X3D, are you referring to the x3d standard for 3d content, as at http://www.web3d.org  If so, I would very much like to learn more of what you are doing -- thanks

Comment: @VincentMarchetti, I am using the x3d standard for 3d content, but not for a web application. This is an open library for haptics (H3D.org) which uses X3D for static content and Python to add dynamics to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. find where numpy is installed on your system. For me, it's here:
   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
2. import it explicitly before importing numpy

`import sys`

`sys.path.append('/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7')`

... if you need help finding the correct path, check the contents of sys.path while using your python interpreter

`import sys`

`print sys.path`

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. I checked the `sys.path` and the correct path is there, I am not sure why this isn't working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had other issues which were not allowing this to work. I had to go into regedit and modify the value for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command`. It was set to Python25 and so I just changed it to Python26. It now works fine with the `import sys` statement you provided.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that your #! line is pointing to a different python interpreter then the one you use normally. Make sure they point to the same one.

Comment: Where would this "#!" be located? I tried the same code in another machine and it seems to work fine, but the one where I need it to work is still giving problems.

Comment: @jaykex, The first line, if your first line doesn't start with #! then you aren't using this feature and my guess is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add the num.py libraries to `sys.path` before you call `import`